# Openshift cron job curl

Tags: cron, openshift, openshift-3

I have Java Rest application on Openshift. I need to create cron for link in my application. Is it possible?

I tried this example

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
  jobTemplate:             
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:          
            parent: "cronjobpi"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: perl
            command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

this job works well, but I dont know how I need to change it from perl to curl correctly.

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can run `curl` command if you change the `image` to `rhel7` as follows.

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: pi
    image: rhel7
    command: ["curl",  "-kvs", "https://www.google.com/"]
...
```

I hope it help you. :^)

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems like it works. But now I vae tens cron jobs. Do you know how I can delete it?

Comment: If you configured same `label` in the `CronJob`, you can delete `oc delete all -l label=value`. Or you can delete the `project/namespace` and recreate it.

Comment: the problem is, that I dont have oc cli console, I use oc web interface, where is no console command