# OpenShift curl POST request

Tags: curl, http-post, openshift, rhel7

I'm trying to do a simple http-post-request from a CronJob to another Deployment in OpenShift. Get-Requests work just fine, but I cannot figure out, how to adapt the curl-command to execute a http-post.
For the get-request I used this: [Openshift cron job curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779748/openshift-cron-job-curl)

I tried many thins. Here two manifest-snippets, which don't work

```
containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: rhel7
    command:
      - curl
      - '-X POST'
      - '-kvs'
      - >-
        http://target-deployment:8080/api/v1/sync/triggerAction
```

.

```
containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: rhel7
    command:
      - curl
      - '-X POST -kvs'
      - >-
        http://target-deployment:8080/api/v1/sync/triggerAction
```

Thanks for any ideas and your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, I just use another image. Curl has an official docker hub image.
The code, that works for me, looks like:

```
containers:
   - name: my-container
     image: curlimages/curl:7.82
     command:
       - sh
       - '-c'
     args:
       - >-
         curl -X POST -ks
         http://target-deployment:8080/api/v1/sync/triggerAction
```